# How to update only one field on a table with specific id

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a table with multiple fields and i want to update only one when same ID.The code that im using to update is next

```
<?php
require('db.php');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
include("auth.php"); //include auth.php file on all secure pages
$status = "";
if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1){
     $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
     $query = "SELECT * from base where `id`='$id'"; 
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die ( mysql_error());
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
     $scantime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
     $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
     $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
     $surname =$_REQUEST['surname'];
     $name= $_REQUEST['name'];
     $company_name=$_REQUEST['company_name'];
     $firm= $_REQUEST['firm'];
     $visitors= $_REQUEST['visitors'];
     $barcode= $_REQUEST['barcode'];
     $submittedby = $_SESSION["username"];
     $update="update base set `scantime`='$scantime' where `id`='$id'";
     mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_error());
 }
?>
```

To search data i using ajax autocomplete function

```
require_once 'config.php';
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
if($_POST['type'] == 'country_table'){
    $row_num = $_POST['row_num'];
    $surname = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SELECT  custId,id,name, surname, company_name, firm,barcode,trn_date,scantime FROM base where UPPER(surname) LIKE '".strtoupper($surname)."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['barcode'].'|'.$row['surname'].'|'.$row['name'].'|'.$row['company_name'].'|'.$row['firm'].'|'.$row['trn_date'].'|'.$row['scantime'].'|'.$row['id'].'|'.$row['custId'].'|'.$row_num;
        array_push($data, $name);   
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And to fill data to input fields

```
$('#barcodescanr').autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: 'barcodescanr',
               row_num : 1
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[0],
                        value: code[0],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                    
        $('#name_1').val(names[2]);
        $('#company_name_1').val(names[3]);
        $('#surname_1').val(names[1]);
        $('#firm_1').val(names[4]);
        $('#info').val(names[5]);
        $('#scanbartime').val(names[6]);
        $('#Id').val(names[7]);
        $('#custId').val(names[8]);
    },
    open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }               
 });
```

The problem that i have is that when i press submit to form it doesnt update scantime .
Thank you

Comment: Where does the code hang? Doesn't look like you are sending a form element named `new`.

Comment: id doesnt update scantime of a person in database with specific ID

Comment: Does it enter that conditional at all?

Comment: No only if i change update statement to insert into base ... on duplicate key update it makes a new record but it doesnt update the current one

Comment: What, it enters the conditional only if you modify something in the conditional? Doesn't sound possible..

Comment: @chris85 i dont want an insert function because add's new record instead of updating current one